# Looking for a right pattern. Data encapsulation. Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, encapsulation

Looking for the right pattern.

Suppose you have some object `Data` you work with that feeds into `HistoricalData` object (as new `Data` comes in and becomes available)

You do something with both `Data` and `HistoricalData`. Once you crunch the numbers you derive a bunch of things from the `HistoricalData`. You would like to offer access to the data you derived via common class `**DerivedData**`.

**Currently**

`Data` (feeds to) --> `HistoricalData` (used to calculate) --> `ClassA`

`Data` (feeds to) --> `HistoricalData` (used to calculate) --> `ClassB`

Each class can be accessed independently

**I'd like to**

`Data` (feeds to) --> `HistoricalData` (used by) --> `DerivedData` (providing access to) --> `ClassA`

`Data` (feeds to) --> `HistoricalData` (used by) --> `DerivedData` (providing access to) --> `ClassB`

ClassA and ClassB can only be accessed via the DerivedData singleton
I'd like to expressly forbid for classes ClassA and ClassB to be accessed directly.

**Please suggest a pattern** i should investigate to accomplish this

Comment: It might help if we knew a bit more about what you were designing :-)

Comment: Are you sure you need a "pattern"?  Or a singleton?  Maybe DerivedData is a list of Data...and...ClassA / ClassB implement DerivedData?  Simple is good.

Comment: Seems to me like a trading/temporal statistics system, no ?

Comment: ++ to David Bullock. Also, be careful not to over complicate things. Sometimes too much abstraction can actually work against you. More often than not simplicity is the easiest thing.

Comment: I honestly am not convinced i need a pattern, this is true. Pattern might be cleaner then making data inside ClassA and B private and hidden inside DerivedData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DerivedData should just be an interface not a singleton.

Comment: This won't help with ClassA/B from being accessed directly though, will it?

Comment: Yes it will.  Make either class C that implements DerivedData and contains Class A and Class B or just combine the two classes and make it implement DerivedData.   The DerivedData interface is what is exposed to other classes.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to consider [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) or [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You may do all this things to achieve what you want:

- Declare ClassA & ClassB as Internal classes of DerivedData
- Declare interfaces ClassAInterface & ClassBInterface for hiding ClassA & ClassB details , and also even hide classA & classB import at DerivedData "client" side.
- Make DerivedData provide a method to return ClassAInterface & ClassBInterface to provide access to the classA & classB functionality exposed through the ClassAInterface & ClassBInterface.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If ClassA and ClassB can be treated in a uniform fashion, make DerivedData an interface / abstract class, then subclass ClassA and ClassB from DerivedData (jzd already pointed out that). In that way, you provide a consistent API to your client code through DerivedData interface.

(2) If ClassA and ClassB are inherently different and HistoricalData as well as the client code need to treat them differently, Abstract Factory or Builder pattern is suitable as Vincenzo already pointed out.

Context is import, IMHO.

---

You said, "I'd like to expressly forbid for classes ClassA and ClassB to be accessed directly." My understanding is that you don't want to explicitly instantiate ClassA and ClassB in the client code, rather you want to obtain their instances from HistoricalData.

I see no point at making DerivedData singleton.